# При попытке обратиться к созданному пространству имен выдает:

Tags: c#

only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

сам код по ссылке

https://i.stack.imgur.com/msYY3.png

Comment: извиняюсь,забыл вставить код

Comment: Вы знаете, когда вы не вставили код - я всего лишь проголосовал за закрытие. Но когда вы решили вставить код картинкой - я поставил минус. Привыкайте вставлять код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Я советую вам ознакомиться хотя бы с основами языка C#, прочитать [пару книг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) и уже затем пытаться что либо написать.

Answer (score 1):

Что делать? Que, так сказать, faire?

```
(new TestHello.Word()).ToString();
```